# how to fit html Contents to QWebView size

Tags: c++, qt, symbian, qwebview

I'm writing code to display html content in Qwebview, i did it by setHtml method of QWebview.
I also disabled scrollbars successfully.

But i stuck with problem that how to make contents to fit to size of QWebView.

please help..

Comment: Possible duplicate (also see the comment in the answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810895/how-to-stretch-shrink-html-page-to-fit-in-qwebview-window/10813410#10813410

Comment: It's different point dude... My Question about how to fit html card to  QWebView size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve that problem by setting Zoom level 
Actually if you want to fit html content to Qwebview size use,

qWebView->setZoomFactor(0.5); set according to your htmlContent size .